# How can I setup a wordpress site with multi country & multi lingual support

Tags: customization, multi-language

We need to create a website for a large company that is present in 4 continents. Content, services and contact information for each region will be different. Moreover, each region may have the website in regional language.

Example :

- Asia will be in English
- Middle East will be in English and Arabic
- Europe will be in English, French and Spanish.

Also, there will be one theme across all regions. The name of the company is the same. Content for each region will be targeted in search engines for each region.

What is the best way to setup wordpress to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

You can create this type of functionality using wordpress **multi site** functionality, But i am not sure about for multi lingual support for multi site, so learn more about for multi site functionality then you may get something about multi lingual.